# youtube_it throws ArgumentError after update to Ruby 2 - how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube, ruby-2.0

I have an application that has a task which scrape a site and then post a video to youtube with some of the information grabbed.

After updating the application to ruby 2, the youtube upload stopped working and started showing the following:

```
(ArgumentError) "wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)"
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/youtube_it 2.1.13/lib/youtube_it/chain_io.rb:66:in `read'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:202:in `copy_stream'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:202:in `send_request_with_body_stream'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:132:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `block in transport_request'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1402:in `catch'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1402:in `transport_request'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:25:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:39:in `trace_http_request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:24:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1368:in `block in request'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1366:in `request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:25:in `block in request_with_newrelic_trace'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/cross_app_tracing.rb:39:in `trace_http_request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb:24:in `request_with_newrelic_trace'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:75:in `perform_request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:38:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/youtube_it-2.1.13/lib/youtube_it/middleware/faraday_authheader.rb:17:in `call'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:247:in `run_request'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:112:in `post'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/youtube_it-2.1.13/lib/youtube_it/request/video_upload.rb:92:in `upload'
/home/deployer/apps/project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/youtube_it-2.1.13/lib/youtube_it/client.rb:106:in `video_upload'
/home/deployer/apps/project/current/app/models/cme_event.rb:169:in `upload_on_youtube'
```

It's a simple silly error about number of arguments which seems to be **net/http**  passing two arguments to the function instead of the previous one. I tried to change the code on the **youtube_it** gem by adding additional optional parameters, but still no luck.

So anyone know what might have changed with **net/http** on ruby 2 that broke this?

Comment: Have you found any work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in new version of youtube_it gem (2.3.2) See also:

https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/issues/159
https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/issues/167

Comment: Thanks @MarcinChrost. I opened that first issue, just haven't time to check it yet.